# cors headers issue google map api in react js after deployed in cpanel

Tags: reactjs, cpanel

cors headers issue google map api in cpanel reactjs.

Cors header issue google map api in react js after deployed in cpanal
locally i have no issue.How to fix in cpanal.
is there any change in htaccess file in cpanal.can anyone fix this issue?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.